# How to split string separated numbers

Tags: python, string, split, python-2.7

I have a long string separated with ordinal numbers. For example: "1. Good morning 2. Hello 3. Bye" (but it is not compulsory that there is a number at beginning and I don't knew how many numbers are there, if any.) and I would like to get list like this: `["Good morning", "Hello", "Bye"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [1]: s = '1. Good morning 2. Hello 3. Bye'

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.split('\d+\. ', s)
Out[3]: ['', 'Good morning ', 'Hello ', 'Bye']
```

If there's no number in the beginning, the first element will not be empty. However, this doesn't check that the numbers are in correct order. Let me know if this is important.

**Edit:** thanks to @**glglgl** for the comment. Splitting on `' *\d+\. *'` may be better in terms of leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew abut split with regex in python.
I'm sure that numbers will be in correct order.

Comment: +1 for `re.split()`, I keep forgetting about that :) My solution ends up with the same output `re.sub('\d+','', s).split('.')` but is more complicated.

Comment: @Levon yours may have a pitfall of eliminating numbers inside phrases. Mine won't do that unless the numbers are followed by a period and a space: `'1. Good morning 2. Hello 3. Bye 5. I have 5 dogs in my kitchen'`

Comment: @LevLevitsky You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I'm still learning my way around regular expressions. Plus your solution is just conceptually more straight forward and clean

Comment: I didn't try, but maybe `' *\d+\. '`would be better on order to eat the whitespace before the numbers...

Comment: It is. Good point, @glglgl, thanks. I'm not sure if I should edit the answer after it's accepted though...

Comment: @LevLevitsky I would edit it,but not change what is already there, but add a note which states that this RE might be better.

Comment: I wrote my own regex so it doesn't matter. I need re.split() ;)